# Unable to convert data type

Tags: sql, hash, sql-server-2016

```
SELECT *
FROM Registration
WHERE UserPass = CONVERT(VARBINARY(50),'5avag3',1);
```

I'm trying to store that password into my database as hash value. Right now the attribute UserPass is in binary and I'm getting this error message:

> Implicit conversion from data type varchar to binary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Code:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Registration] ([LoginName], [UserPass], [FirstName],[LastName], [PIC], [DIC])
VALUES ('LogPaul', '', 'Logan', 'Paul', '', '690404-10-5827')
```

When I try to convert the data type it says I'm unable to convert.

Please help I'm new to SQL, thanks in advance

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s I'm using MS SQL server 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just perform the conversion to binary inside the actual `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Registration] ([LoginName], [UserPass], [FirstName], [LastName],
                                  [PIC], [DIC])
VALUES
    ('LogPaul', CONVERT(VARBINARY(50),'5avag3',1), 'Logan', 'Paul', '',
     '690404-10-5827')
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but i followed that but i still get "Error converting data type varchar to varbinary."

Comment: What is the type of the `DIC` column?

Comment: DIC column is the foreign key from another table called Driver, i have set it null

Comment: ('LogPaul', CAST('5avag3' AS VARBINARY(64)), 'Logan', 'Paul', '','690404-10-5827')

Comment: @JasmineMontez It was unclear which column you want as binary.

Comment: sorry my bad, I want UserPass as binary. I want to store the password as hash, not sure if my syntax and logic is correct